# CSRF error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I have a problem in Laravel . when over and over submit Form with post method and somtimes I get error and see expire error that related to CSRF
anybody knows how can I manage this error that display not in site and instead of redirect to any page else ?

Comment: seems like you are not sending "csrf" token while posting form data.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF).
Just add `@csrf` blade directive inside the form to avoid getting csrf token error.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

The directive puts something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="CzK6peomC6Pnnqdm4NsxpdGSH6v1evDnbN12oL" >
```

Read more about it in the laravel documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

Regarding the expiration of the token I think you might want to handle the error this way https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e

Also, there's a package which helps the forms keep awake.
https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 using Blades templates, it's easy.
Add csrf toke in your blade file

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

If you are using Laravel 5.6 then you need to add something like this in your code of the form

```
@csrf
```

Check in detail about: [CSRF Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-introduction)